How to modify an RDS Cluster from serverless v1 to provisioned engine mode in place using terraform?
We are upgrading an RDS Cluster from serverless v1 to serverless v2. To do that using in-place upgrade strategy, first we have to upgrade to provisioned and then to serverless v2.
When I change my engine_mode from serverless to provisioned, it is being replace instead of modifying which will cause data loss.
I took a snapshot and restored as a new cluster and then modifying it to provisioned engine mode. When I do that cluster is being replaced instead of modifying. Is there any way that I can modify it to provisioned  only in terraform?
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  cluster_identifier = "my-rds-cluster"
  engine_mode = "serverless" 
  engine_version = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.4"
  engine = "aurora-mysql"

  scaling_configuration{
    # More code
  }

}

When I try to edit this and convert to provisioned, my cluster is being replaced instead of modifying
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  cluster_identifier = "my-rds-cluster"
  engine_mode = "provisioned" 
  engine_version = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.4"
  engine = "aurora-mysql"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "instance" {
  identifier = "instance"
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.my_cluster.id
  instance_class = "db.r5.xlarge"

  # Rest of code
}


"I took a snapshot and restored as a new cluster and then modifying it to provisioned engine mode" Why didn't you restore the snapshot directly to a provisioned mode cluster? Why did you restore it to another serverless v1 cluster?
